# Remove specific stylesheets from a given page

Tags: 7, theming

Adding a stylesheet to specific pages is easy: implement `hook_preprocess_page()`, call `drupal_add_css(...)` and set `$vars['styles'] = drupal_get_css()`.

---

But what is the proper way to *remove* a stylesheet (or in my case, all "media=screen" stylesheets) for a specific page, without interfering with the caching system ? (e.g. not some regex applied to the output)

You can't just do `unset($vars['css']['screen'])` because `$vars['styles']` has already been generated at this point and there exists no `drupal_remove_css()` function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be the cleanest way, in `hook_preprocess_page()`:

```
$css = drupal_add_css();
unset( $css['screen'] );
$vars['styles'] = drupal_get_css($css);
```