# Is there a reason I need to unset CSS files provided by contrib modules if I have CSS aggregation enabled?

Tags: theming, performance

As [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/736/5147) makes clear, stylesheets provided by modules can be unset.  Some themes, such as Adaptivetheme 3.x, also provide a GUI for unsetting the stylesheets provided by modules.  My question is this: if I have CSS aggregation enabled, is there any benefit to unsetting CSS files of modules I do not use?  Or is Drupal's CSS aggregation sufficiently efficient that I do not need to bother with unsetting any files?

Comment: If the CSS is supplied by modules you do not use, ie. the modules are disabled, then that CSS won't be added to the page. Do you mean CSS from enabled modules that you have overridden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to unset css files to avoid css limits by 
ie 7 and 8, such as

Maximum number of possible selectors in a CSS file - 4095
and 31 stylesheets per file

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11080846

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it unsetting CSS stylesheets is to:

- reduce the final size of the aggregrated css file(s)
- more easily override / implement custom CSS rules

Beyond these 2 reasons, your site probably "uses" all css files defined in the modules you have activated. Unless you need the performance boost from cutting out the extra bloat of X css files, or want to hand-theme certain things completely .... I see little need to unset style sheets.

I've only unset style sheets once .... and it's probably because i'm not making use of drupals multisite capabability where i have 1 site resolving from 2 url domains: http://www.foo.com and https://secure.webhost.com/foo.com/page depending on the domain I use a hook to unset/set a CSS files that fixes image paths in CSS when i'm on a secure url.