# Specify a single node to load a stylesheet on

Tags: theming, 7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to add CSS for a single page/node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/126/any-way-to-add-css-for-a-single-page-node)

How do I make it so that when a specific node loads (a page with path /some/page) that it also loads a specific stylesheet?

Comment: I was wanting to load down a stylesheet as opposed to manually entered commands into each node. I'm removing the answer tag from Jim to see if anyone knows how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several very good solutions, please see the question "**[Any way to add CSS for a single page/node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/126/any-way-to-add-css-for-a-single-page-node)**"