# How to add js file in only 1 node?

Tags: javascript

I made a custom js script for a little calculator. I want to use this in only 1 node (article or page) so I do not want to load it via tpl files etc because I do not need it sitewide. And also: if every custom script (that I use only in 1 node) has to be loaded sitewide I would get an immense head section after some time. Does anyone have experience with how to do this in a simple and safe way?

Thanks.
Frank

Comment: It's the same as http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/126/any-way-to-add-css-for-a-single-page-node only you have to use [`drupal_add_js()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_add_js/7) instead.

Comment: Just use hook_node_view and with condition add js using drupal_add_js.

Comment: Is there a chance that the js will be use in other part of te site?

Answer (score 2):

In the `template.php` you will write this small piece of code:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node($vars) {
 if (drupal_get_path_alias("node/{$vars['#node']->nid}") == 'yournid') {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . "/script/js");
 }
}
```

Replace foo with values related to your need.

Answer (score 0):

code for adding JS to particular path:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/path/to/node') {
  drupal_add_js('somefile.js');
}
```

to attach js to node:

```
function my_module_node_view($node, $viewmode, $langcode) {
  $node->content['#attached']['js'][] = array('type' => 'file','data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/my_script.js',);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [JS Injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/js_injector). Though I haven't used this module. This requires no  programming as it provides user interface to administrators.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use php filter or need to create tpl file for single node to accomplish this. With php filter or tpl you need to put only this code.

```
<?php 
  drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("p").hide();
    jQuery("p").fadeIn("slow");
  });', 'inline');
?>
```

Comment: PHP filter is highly discouraged.

Comment: I understand it creates a potential security risk especially in the hands of end users or people new to Drupal or PHP.