# How to load .css file only on your custom 404 Not Found page?

Tags: 7, theming

Following [this guide](https://cheekymonkeymedia.ca/blog/custom-drupal-404-pages) I created a custom `page--404.tpl.php` page for my custom 404 Not found page. We put this in `template.php`:

```
function themename_preprocess_page(&$vars) {    
 // Adds a Custom 404 page    
 $header = drupal_get_http_header("status");    
 if($header == "404 Not Found") {        
   $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__404';    
 }    
}
```

Now I need to load CSS only when that page is loaded. [This here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/126/any-way-to-add-css-for-a-single-page-node) only shows how to load it in either node or front page, but not custom 404 page.

This does not work:

```
    $header = drupal_get_http_header("status");
    if($header == "404 Not Found") {
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__404';
      drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'dev') . "css/404/bootstrap.css");
      drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'dev') . "css/404/custom-style.css");
    }

}
```

Comment: You can simply try adding `drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . "/css/foo.css");` in your if condition, if that works. Because you're already checking header.

Comment: Hi @Yogesh please check edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Yogesh, you should use `drupal_add_css`. Your code cannot work because you have missing slash. Please use below code.

```php
function themename_preprocess_page(&$vars) {    
 // Adds a Custom 404 page    
 $header = drupal_get_http_header("status");    
 if($header == "404 Not Found") {        
   $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__404';
   drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'dev') . "/css/404/bootstrap.css");
   drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'dev') . "/css/404/custom-style.css");
 }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to use [CSS Injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/css_injector). It would allow you to load CSS based upon the path. Might be a simpler solution but may not do exactly what you require.